# how to debug in openlayers on Vue,except using console?

Tags: vue.js, debugging, openlayers

guys.  i'm a beginner in developing openlayers project on Vue.
i found its hard to debug olpenlayers for me.
For example, i create a element in openlayers map, but it didnot appear, so how can i find the problem?  In past,i only can console the element value ,and try to guess.

excuse me , maybe there is a more effective to debug for openlayers? like a gui can debug it in browser easily,show the current map's state?

i used to console the log for debugging, but its not intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` is the most common way to debug things - also OpenLayers. You can also use the browser dev tools to explore the DOM and get insights from that.

If the map does not show up at all, there are many options what could be wrong. Very often the element you are mounting OL to has no width/height. The first thing to try is to create a simple `div` with a pink background. When you can see that, than you can try to mount a OpenLayers map as well.

Here are some ressources using OpenLayer with Vue:

- [Wegue](https://github.com/wegue-oss/wegue/)
- [Post](https://spatial-dev.guru/2022/02/20/integrating-openlayers-map-with-vuejs-create-map-part-1/)
- [vue3-openlayers](https://github.com/MelihAltintas/vue3-openlayers)
- [vuelayers](https://github.com/ghettovoice/vuelayers)
- [vue-ol-comp](https://github.com/JakobMiksch/vue-ol-comp)